# WooCommerce Variations Table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a variable Table, that I need to show stock levels per location - and not the total stock for each product - as it currently is.

The plugin used: Woocommerce Variations to Table - Grid

Added the fields in the variation by the functions.php method

below is the code that the Variations Table Grid use to show the stock number.

```
<?php
        if ($vartable_stock == 1) {

          if (absint($vartable_low_stock_thresh) > 0 && $varstock < absint($vartable_low_stock_thresh) && get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_manage_stock', true) == 'yes' ) {
            $allcolumns['vartable_stock'] = '<td class="stockcol" data-label="'. apply_filters('vartable_dl_stock', $headenames['vartable_stock'], $value) .'">'. (get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_stock_status', true) != 'outofstock' && $varstock > 0 ? '<span class="lowstock">'. str_replace ('%n', $varstock, __($vartable_low_stock_text, 'vartable')) .'</span>' : '<span class="outofstock">'.__($vartable_out_stock_text, 'vartable').'</span>') .'</td>';
          } else {
            $allcolumns['vartable_stock'] = '<td class="stockcol" data-label="'. apply_filters('vartable_dl_stock', $headenames['vartable_stock'], $value) .'">'. (get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_stock_status', true) != 'outofstock' ? '<span class="instock">'. str_replace ('%n', $varstock, __($vartable_in_stock_text, 'vartable')) .'</span>' : '<span class="outofstock">'.__($vartable_out_stock_text, 'vartable').'</span>') .'</td>';
          }

        }
      ?>
```

This shows the Stock Levels for each variation as seen in the image below.

[image]

Here is what it looks like in the backend of the product:

[image]

Here is the code that I used for adding those four custom fields into the product variation.

```html
// 1. Add custom field input @ Product Data > Variations > Single Variation

add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'stock_warehouse_add_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 3 );
// Durban Stock Number
function stock_warehouse_add_custom_field_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
'id' => 'stock_level_durban[' . $loop . ']',
'class' => 'short',
'label' => __( 'Durban Stock', 'woocommerce' ),
'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'stock_level_durban', true )
)
);
// Cape Town Stock Number
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
'id' => 'stock_level_cape_town[' . $loop . ']',
'class' => 'short',
'label' => __( 'Cape Town Stock', 'woocommerce' ),
'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'stock_level_cape_town', true )
)
);
// PE Stock Number
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
'id' => 'stock_level_pe[' . $loop . ']',
'class' => 'short',
'label' => __( 'Port Elizabeth Stock', 'woocommerce' ),
'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'stock_level_pe', true )
)
);
// JHB Stock Number
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
'id' => 'stock_level_jhb[' . $loop . ']',
'class' => 'short',
'label' => __( 'JHB Stock', 'woocommerce' ),
'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'stock_level_jhb', true )
)
);
}

// -----------------------------------------
// 2. Save custom field on product variation save

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'stock_warehouse_save_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 2 );

function stock_warehouse_save_custom_field_to_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
$stock_level_durban = $_POST['stock_level_durban'][$i];
if ( isset( $stock_level_durban ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'stock_level_durban', esc_attr( $stock_level_durban ) );
$stock_level_cape_town = $_POST['stock_level_cape_town'][$i];
if ( isset( $stock_level_cape_town ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'stock_level_cape_town', esc_attr( $stock_level_cape_town ) );
$stock_level_pe = $_POST['stock_level_pe'][$i];
if ( isset( $stock_level_pe ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'stock_level_pe', esc_attr( $stock_level_pe ) );
$stock_level_jhb = $_POST['stock_level_jhb'][$i];
if ( isset( $stock_level_jhb) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'stock_level_jhb', esc_attr( $stock_level_jhb) );
}

// -----------------------------------------
// 3. Store custom field value into variation data

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'stock_warehouse_add_custom_field_variation_data' );

function stock_warehouse_add_custom_field_variation_data( $variations ) {
  $variations['stock_level_durban'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">Durban Stock: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'stock_level_durban', true ) . '</span></div>';
  $variations['stock_level_cape_town'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">Cape Town Stock: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'stock_level_cape_town', true ) . '</span></div>';
  $variations['stock_level_pe'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">PE Stock: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'stock_level_pe', true ) . '</span></div>';
  $variations['stock_level_jhb'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">JHB Stock: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'stock_level_jhb', true ) . '</span></div>';
  return $variations;
}

function woo_hide_product_categories_widget( $list_args ){
        $list_args[ 'hide_empty' ] = 1;
        return $list_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woo_hide_product_categories_widget' );

add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
  $new_terms = array();
  // if a product category and on the shop page
  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'uncategorized' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }
    }
    $terms = $new_terms;
  }
  return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', function( $text ) {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $text = $product->is_purchasable() ? __( 'View', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'View', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}, 10 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'rename_color_attribute_label', 10, 3);

function rename_color_attribute_label($label, $name, $product){
  if(strtolower($label)=='colour'){
    $label = 'Variant';
  }
  return $label;
}
```

I am trying to get the SOH to show like 0/0/0/28 instead of just the total "28" so that customers can see where the stock is located and not just the total amount.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help - thanks all.

Comment: I see you've successfully added custom fields to your product variations. But do these fields actually update the stock of you product?

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa- yes they do - it updates to the total stock quantity, but I want to display the four custom fields, and not just the total amount, as clients are wanting to know where the stock is held, not just the total number of stock items.

Comment: Unfortunately, based on the code you provided there doesn't seem to be a filter for the `$varstock` variable. Also I would double check if your custom fields actually update when a customer buys an item. So when someone buys a hat from the JHB location does your custom field go down from 28 to 27? Or does only the stock field decrease and your custom variation fields stay the same?